# Class-based animation without displacing element with ngAnimate

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve the animation effect of the current visible div to fade out and another div to fade in its place, when the corresponding pagination button is clicked.

I was able to get to the point where the divs will properly fade in and fade out.

However, the animation will displace the div about to fade in, below the div about to fade out, for the duration of the transition.

So far this is what I have:

```
// html
<div ng-show="isGroupActive(1)" class="group"></div>
<div ng-show="isGroupActive(2)" class="group"></div>
<div ng-show="isGroupActive(3)" class="group"></div>

<button ng-click="activateGroup(1)">1</button>
<button ng-click="activateGroup(2)">2</button>
<button ng-click="activateGroup(3)">3</button>
```

---

```
// css
.group.ng-hide-add-active {
  display: block!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
.group.ng-hide-remove-active {
  display: block!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.group.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.group.ng-show-add-active {
  display: block!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}

.group.ng-show-remove-active {
  display: block!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.group.ng-show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

```
// js

function MainController($scope) {

  var groupActive = 1;

  $scope.isGroupActive = function(page) {
      return page === groupActive;
  };

  $scope.activateGroup = function(page) {
      groupActive = page;
  }

}

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainController', MainController);
```

I need to avoid the div displacement.

Is this possible just by changing the css transition classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve it just by changing the css classes, but you can achieve this effect (known as "cross-fade") with straight css, and a bit more markup, like so:

Add a container to "contain" the elements, so we can absolutely position them:

```
<div id="container">
    <div ng-show="isGroupActive(1)" class="group"></div>
    <div ng-show="isGroupActive(2)" class="group"></div>
    <div ng-show="isGroupActive(3)" class="group"></div>
</div>
```

Apply `position: relative` to the container:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Then apply `position: absolute` to the divs that need to cross-fade:

```
#container > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;   // adjust as needed
    left: 0;  // adjust as needed
}
```

Comment: Ok, unfortunately all hell breaks loose within `col-*` bootstrap classes.

Comment: Then change the name of the container.  Also, be sure the container is not outside `col-*` elements, but *inside* of them.  If you need more help, post more context with the bootstrap.